# What Language is Raven using for her attacks?

Tags: dc

I know that Teen Titans is based off from DC Works as Robin, Starfire, Raven and Cyborg are supposed to be younger versions of themselves.

I am wondering what language Raven uses in her attacks, if it's a made up language i'd also like to know where i can look up translations (is there is any).

I'm also wondering if the attacks/language used by Raven in Teen Titans is canon to the rest of the DC Universe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **COMICS** [Raven](http://www.dccomics.com/characters/raven) is a half-demon and half-human possessing many abilities inherited from her father [Trigon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigon_%28comics%29). She grew up in an alternate dimension called [Azarath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azarath), with pacifistic inhabitants whose spiritual leader was the mystic Azar.

[image]

**Azar** planned to expel all evil from the Azarathians so that the demon [Trigon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigon_%28comics%29) could use the dark energy to be resurrected and then Azar could finally kill him (NOTE: This ill-conceived plan is similar to that of Lyon Vastia's when he used the Moon Drop to release the demon Deliora from the **Iced Shell** Ur cast upon him in [Fairy Tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tail)).

[image]

The **manta** (or chant) [Raven](http://teentitans.wikia.com/wiki/Raven) uses in the Teen Titans cartoon ["Azarath, Metrion, Zinthos!"] is similar to her mantra and spell-casting she uses/used in comics pre-[New 52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52). Primarily she uses her manta to ease her meditation and as a focus point. As she learned her meditation in [Azarath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azarath) it is my understanding that it is a magical language or words of magical power she draws strength from.

If the words are a specific language it is probable it is Azarathian?

According to the [DC Comics Wiki](http://dc.wikia.com/):

> Raven is fluent in several languages including English, German, Latin, Romanian, Ancient Sumerian, and Sanskrit.

Further:

> Raven is well-versed in the occult and is familiar with the magical and mystical rites from both her home dimension Azarath as well as Earth.

Comment: Why is Raven standing on a woman's head in that first cover?

Comment: Haha... I'm pretty sure that's her own face.  That image is from a pin-up of Raven and I bet the artist wanted to draw her face not just in shadow... so it's the "artistic licence" defense =P

Comment: "mantra",  not "manta"?

Answer (score 8):

#### [Raven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_%28comics%29) isn't using a language at all.

- She is using a chant to focus and release her demonic abilities in the form of darkform constructs, the release of her soul self or the projection of demonic fire or magical energies. Raven's demonic nature grants her vast magical powers and demonic abilities inherited from her father, the demon [Trigon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigon_%28comics%29).
- She is focusing her will using the chant of "Azarath, Metrion, Zinthos!" Of the three words, only [Azarath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azarath) has a known meaning, as it was the home of Raven and her people the Azar. Raven left Azarath's pacifist society in another dimension to try to leave her demon heritage behind and become good by joining the Teen Titans.
- In the Teen Titans Go! cartoon, her powers are very similar to the depictions in the comics with the caveat she is far more liberal in their use in the cartoon. In her comic depictions she is more reserved in the use of her powers, since they could at any time release her demonic nature.

Answer (score 0):

Metrios in Greek or Hellenic apparently means evenly measured, middling, or equality according to one of our Ancient Cities readings for college. Metrion may be a derivative of that. So whatever nonsense words she is using may be based off of ancient Greek language and may hold some actual significance. My thought is that, as Azarath is her idyllic homeworld, and Earth often being depicted as a middle ground between dimensions, she may be saying something like, "Heaven, Earth, Hell," with her demonic powers triggering at hell.

Comment: But is this just speculation...?

Comment: Yes. But I think it's pretty sweet speculation.